# jQuery selector question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

New to jQuery.

I  have the following html:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/" method="post"> 
      <div class="field"> 
          <label for="id_profile_pic">Profile Pic</label> 
          <input type="file" name="profile_pic" id="id_profile_pic" /> 
      </div> 

      <div> 
      <span>Profile Picture</span> 
      <img src="/site_media/profile_pic/4e17c792-3c34-4556-8c67-135bc931eb5a.jpg"/> 
      <input type="button" value="Upload" id="upload_button" /> 
      </div> 
  </form>
```

And I need help with the selector in the following function

```
  $('#upload_button').click(function() {
    //how can I select the file input element (ie. #id_profile_pic) here? 
  });
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean saying "select"? Focus on this element? Or open a select file dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could target that element just as you targeted the first in your initial selector:

```
  $("#id_profile_pic").doStuff();
```

Was there something more you were intending to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to select that element?  You would do it with `$('#id_profile_pic')` but shouldn't you just be submitting the form so it actually uploads?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#upload_button').click(function() {
    // to select it here you just need
    $('#id_profile_pic')

});
```

if you want to select all the pictures in the form you can use:

```
$('#upload_button').click(function() {

    $(this).parent().find('img');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the exact same way: with a hash (`#`):

```
$('#upload_button').click(function() {
    var fileUploadPic = $('#id_profile_pic');

    var value = fileUploadPic.val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it too:

```
$('#upload_button').click(function(){
  var file = $(this).closest('form').find('input[type=file]') ;
  return ;
} ;
```

This will find the file control(s) in the form being posted, regardless of markup structure (and without needed to know the control ID).

[TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), as the perl monks say.